# A question on Fargues-Scholze

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, langlands-conjectures

As far as I understand it, the main goal of the recent work of Fargues and Scholze on the geometrization conjecture is to show that the local Langlands conjecture of a local field is equivalent to the geometric Langlands conjecture for the corresponding Fargues-Fontaine curve (according to [this lecture of Lurie](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/ffcurve/Lecture1-Overview.pdf) we can take this as an "heuristic slogan").

If I understand the introduction of the Fargues-Scholze paper correctly, the "geometric Langlands" in question relates $D(Bun_G,\mathcal{O})^{\omega}$ and the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on $Z^1(W_E,\hat{G})_{\mathcal{O}}/\hat{G})$, that is Conjecture I.10.2 (or the "rational coefficients"-version Conjecture X.1.4).

There are two things that I'd like to ask about: the relation to the function field case and geometric object $Z^1(W_E,\hat{G})/\hat{G}$. If I understand it(or rather surveys about it) correctly, the Geometrization conjecture implies that conjecture X.1.4 for the local field $E$ implies the local Langlands for the local field $E$. If I understand the remark imediately after Conjecture I.10.2, the authors conjecture this geometric statement also in the function field case. So does the Geometrization conjecture also tell us that we can prove local Langlands in the function field case via this geometric conjecture?

And finally how is $Z^1(W_E,\hat{G})/\hat{G}$ related to the Fargues-Fontaine curve? Since it classfies maps from $W_E$ to $\hat{G}$, and by construction the étale site of the Fargues-Fontaine curve understands $W_E$, it would seem reasonable to see $Z^1(W_E,\hat{G})/\hat{G}$ as the moduli space of local systems on the Fargues-Fontaine curve. Presumably heuristically this isn't far from the truth, but what is the "benefit" to work with this quotient instead of the **Edit: moduli space of $\hat{G}$-local systems on the** Fargues-Fontaine curve?

Finally let me just apologize for the question.

Comment: All of our results apply to all nonarchimedean local fields, including the ones of equal characteristic (i.e., the function field case). And one could indeed consider $Z^1(W_E,\hat{G})/\hat{G}$ as a moduli space of $\hat{G}$-local systems on the Fargues-Fontaine curve; but as the Fargues-Fontaine curve enters here only via $W_E$, this seems like "overkill", so we preferred the more classical perspective. I don't understand the final "... instead of the Fargues-Fontaine curve"; certainly the moduli space of $\hat{G}$-local systems on the FF curve is quite different from the FF curve itself?

Comment: @PeterScholze thanks for your answer!  "... instead of the Fargues-Fontaine curve" is a typo on my end.

Comment: One point to emphasize is that there was no definitive formulation of "the" Local Langlands Conjecture to begin with, for general groups. (There were predictions of the form "there should be a finite-to-1 map between two infinite sets satisfying some properties..." but this was not a precise Conjecture.) The Geometrization Conjecture is one way to make a precise statement that captures almost all of the properties we expect from Local Langlands, although it's not clear that it captures everything. The relation to Kaletha et al's approach to LLC stands out as an open problem...

Comment: Yes, the precise relation between our conjecture and other formulations of the local Langlands correspondence is far from clear; but at least it gives something to hold on to. About why we are not calling it the moduli space of $\hat{G}$-local systems on the Fargues-Fontaine curve: The main reason is that the moduli space of $L$-parameters has been considered before, and it doesn't require one to know anything about the Fargues-Fontaine curve. (Also, when $G$ is not split, it gets slightly nasty to say what is meant by $\hat{G}$-local systems.)